# Pandas reading empty rows into dataframe from csv

Tags: python, dataframe

I am reading a csv into a dataframe using:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

My csv has 800 rows of data, but my dataframe is reading in 805 rows. The last 5 rows are completely blank. Is there any way to remove these 5 empty rows?

Comment: you can use built-in function `dropna()` for NaN data

Comment: you can also try `df=pd.read_csv('file.csv', skipfooter=5)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use slice with [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to remove last 5 rows, if you don't bother reading the data again and just want to work with the current copy:

```
df = df.iloc[:-5]
```

Or use [`head`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.head.html):

```
df.head(-5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options when using the `read_csv()` from pandas which is documented [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html).

I think the easiest one-time argument you can pass into the function would be along the lines of `pd.read_csv('file.csv', skiprows = 801:805)`

For more reusable code you can try some of the others on that site like `skip_blank_lines` which is defaulted to `True` anyways, so make sure those rows are actually blank in your file.